# Create a professional looking calendar for a website form

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am creating a form which requires the user to fill in a date for a booking. I want to have a calendar as a part of the form where the default date is the date for that particular date.

Are there any premade calendars (I don't want to reinvent the wheel)?

I am developing using html, css, javascript, jsp and bootstrap. I don't mind adding another framework in order to make this work. Thank you!

Comment: We are here to help fix programming problems, not do your job for you. You write some code, we'll maybe help try fix it. But until then, you're just asking us to do your job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bootstrappers have many examples of date-time pickers:

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ This has many calender examples. You can easily incorporate this in to your form.

Answer (score 0):

This question should be more technical, but i think this is what you are looking for.
    https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/